# An special example of an integral equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

How can solve the following special integral equation:

$$\int_0^x \frac{x^2 t^3 + t^4 +1}{(x-t)^{\frac{1}{4}}}u(t)\; dt=\frac{128}{231}x^{\frac{11}{4}}+\frac{32768}{100947}x^{\frac{31}{4}}+\frac{262144}{908523}x^{\frac{27}{4}}$$ with $0\leq x\leq 1$?

Which method is suitable for solving it?

Comment: Have you ever heard of Volterra's integral equation (of the first kind)?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Yes of course. But I've  just seen the form $\int_0^x \frac{u(t)}{(x-t)^{\alpha}}\; dt=f(x)$ of Volterra's integral equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you don't want one to 'show' the solution $u$, but if you would like to know what bibliography has to offer, consider [this article on AMS](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1910-011-04/S0002-9947-1910-1500871-9/S0002-9947-1910-1500871-9.pdf).
It mentions that Volterra considers

$$\phi(x) - \phi(a) = \int_a^x\,\frac{G(x,t)}{{(x-t)}^\lambda}\,u(t)\,dt,$$

where $\lambda<1$, $G(x,t)$ and $\partial G/\partial x$ are continuous in the triangular region $a \leq t \leq x \leq b$ and $G(x,x)\neq 0$.
It says

> "this generalization Volterra carries out in the second of
>   his papers appearing in the *Atti di Torino*, and shows that **there is one
>   and only one continuous solution**."

Hence, with $a=0$, $b=1$, $\lambda = 1/4$, $G(x,t) =  x^2t^3+t^4+1$ and

$$\phi(x) = \frac{128}{231}x^{\frac{11}{4}}+\frac{32768}{100947}x^{\frac{31}{4}}+\frac{262144}{908523}x^{\frac{27}{4}},$$

your equation has a unique continuous solution $u$.

---

The reference cited is

> Atti della Reale Accademia delle Scienze di Torino, vol. 31, Jan., 1896, pp.
>   400-408

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunatley, I could not find this paper "Atti della Reale Accademia delle Scienze di Torino, vol. 31, Jan., 1896, pp. 400-408".  Could you explain for me how can find the unique solution of the equation in brief?